# How can I respond to a prompt within a shell script running in background?

Tags: shell-script, background-process, input

I am scripting the installation of software on HP-UX server.  Once the script starts it provides a prompt where I am to enter the install path.  I need to pass the path to the script so it can continue to run.  There is only 1 place in the script where this need exists.

The prompt from the script is:
Press ENTER for default path or enter path to install software:

I do not want to use the default path, so I must enter a new path.  But this script will run in the background and I need to provide the path.  I'm not sure of the exact response in script form.

Comment: Please could you be clearer about what "the script" is?  Is it the installer, which you can't edit for some reason?  Or another script that you are writing to run the installer?  How are you starting the installer, so that it runs in the background?

Comment: Give a look to my answer, and test it!

Answer (score 5):

You can echo your answer into standard input of script by using a pipe.

```
echo "My/Path/not/default"| yourscript.sh
```

Comment: So inside the same script, after the command to run the installer... ./INSTALL silent ... I should insert the following line ...  echo "my/path/not/default/" | installscript.sh  ?

Answer (score 5):

If you can provide all the inputs when the script starts, then do so, by [redirecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) the program's input. That is, instead of running `/path/to/installer`, run

```
{ echo '/the/path/where/to/install';
  echo 'answer to the second prompt';
} | /path/to/installer
```

or use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
/path/to/installer <<'EOF'
/the/path/where/to/install
answer to the second prompt
EOF
```

If you want to interact with a program from time to time but use your terminal for other things in between, run the program in a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) such as [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). With screen, start a session by running `screen`, then start the program. To do something else, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> to create a second window, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd> to navigate between the windows. To exit Screen but leave the program running, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> (“detach”). To come back to the existing Screen session, run `screen -rd` (`screen` with no option would start a new session).

Answer (score 1):

To provide an automatic answer, you could use one of the following:

```
insaller.sh < an_input_file
```

or

```
command-line | installer.sh
```

There is something to notice if the `installer.sh` script is using `read -p`, as in the example below:

```
read -p "Press ENTER for default path or enter path to install software:" answer
```

`man bash` specifies that nothing is printed if the standard input is not a terminal.

If this is your situation, then you could try this odd thing:

```
( sleep 30 ; printf "/my/own/path\n" ) | insaller.sh
```

You should adapt the number of seconds (`30` in above example) to your situation.

If it happens that `read -p` **is not used** inside the install script, then you could give a try to this `GNU` solution:

```
 tempdir="$(mktemp -d)"
 mkfifo  "${tempdir}"/input
 touch "${tempdir}"/output.log
 ./installer.sh <"${tempdir}"/input >"${tempdir}"/output.log 2>&1 &
 installerpid=$!
 tail --pid=$installerpid -fn 1 "${tempdir}"/output.log | ( fgrep -q "Press ENTER for default path or enter path to install software:"; printf "/new/path\n" ) >> "${tempdir}"/input &

 # ... do stuff


 # before ending the script, just wait that all background processes stop
 wait
 rm -f "${tempdir}"/input "${tempdir}"/output.log
```

The idea is to use 2 background command-lines, one for the install script, and one to wait the prompt and provide the answer.

A named pipe (`input`) and a regular file (`output.log`) are used for communication.

`tail --pid=$installerpid -fn 1 "${tempdir}"/output.log` prints lines as there are written in the `output.log` file. It teminates when the installer script terminates.

`( fgrep -q ... ; printf .. ) >> ...input`: blocks until the prompt is found, and provides the new path to the install script.